# Parsing complex string column into new columns in R

Tags: r, parsing

I have the following data:

```
id,response,date
123,{"showAgain":1421547783703,"answer":null,"details":null,"user_id":2423553}, 2015-01-11 02:23:03
124,{"showAgain":1421683620119,"answer":["Never"],"details":null,"user_id":4933822,"company_id":992211,"category":"apple"}, 2015-01-12 16:06:56
125,{"showAgain":1421692043509,"answer":["Sometimes","other"],"details":"I like bread.","user_id":2390922,"company_id":119988,"category":"banana"},2015-01-12 18:27:23
```

To be clear, the "response" column values are what you see within the curly brackets.

I'd need to break that response into new columns, but the string doesn't always have the same number of values. The desired output would be this:

```
id,answer,details,user_id,company_id,category,date
123,NA,NA,2423553,NA,NA,2015-01-11 02:23:03
124,Never,NA,4933822,992211,apple,2015-01-12 16:06:56
125,Other,"I like bread",2390922,119988,banana,2015-01-12 18:27:23
```

The NA can also be blank or NULL, I'm indifferent. 
On row 3 "answer" could also be a concatenation of the two replies "Sometimes.Other". Or it could be broken out into a new column called answer2. There will never be more than 2 values in the incoming "answer" field (95% of time it will be 1 value).

Any clues on how to approach this would be welcome.

Comment: I'd recommend a json parser, like those in packages `jsonlite`, `RJSONIO`, and `rjson`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a start:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(jsonlite)
library(data.table)

lines <- readLines("data.txt")

build_cols <- function(x) {
  data.frame(cbind(id=x[2], date=x[4], rbind(fromJSON(x[3]))))
}

rbindlist(lapply(str_match_all(lines[2:length(lines)], 
                               "([[:digit:]]+),(\\{.*\\}),(.*$)"),
                 build_cols), fill=TRUE) %>%
  select(id,answer,details,user_id,company_id,category,date)

##     id          answer       details user_id company_id category                 date
## 1: 123            NULL          NULL 2423553       NULL     NULL  2015-01-11 02:23:03
## 2: 124           Never          NULL 4933822     992211    apple  2015-01-12 16:06:56
## 3: 125 Sometimes,other I like bread. 2390922     119988   banana  2015-01-12 18:27:23
```

Comment: I get the following error: Error in rbindlist(lapply(str_match_all(lines[2:length(lines)], "([[:digit:]]+),(\\{.*\\}),(.*$)"),  : 
  unused argument (fill = TRUE)  -- I try taking it out but then get this error: Error in UseMethod("select_") : 
  no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "list"